# git-svn: is there a way to get it to play nice with submodules, or ignore them?

Tags: git, version-control, git-svn

once you have a commit that contains a submodule object, you pretty much cannot get git-svn to commit past it.

Any ideas, workarounds, anything that is not "don't use submodules with git-svn"?

So far the answer seems to be a big NO.

Is there any way to at least allow existing git commits containing submodule data to be committed to svn without the submodule data? Even if it means rewriting the tree.

Comment: I'm looking into using sub-tree merges instead of submodules. Makes life easier for people on the plain svn side. It's just normal repo files to them.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to replace the submodules with the `svn:externals` property to play nice with Subversion.

```
svn propset svn:externals [...]
```

I don't think there's any other way round it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an access to the SVN server you may install [SubGit](http://subgit.com) into it. It will create a linked Git repository, such that any push to the Git repository will be translated to the SVN and vice versa. The translation is concurrent-safe, so you may consider this pair of repositories as 2 interfaces (Git and SVN) of the same repository as it is done on GitHub with the difference that the translation is much more transparent (all branches are converted to branches, tags to tags, svn:ignore to .gitginore, svn:eol-style to .gitattributes value and so on).

After that you may add submodules to you resulting Git repository and forget about git-svn.

If you have no access to the server I know no solution, only for svn:externals support from Git (look at SmartGit and .gitsvnextmodules config).